# HAPROXY: Display log messages from external check script to rsyslog

Tags: haproxy, high-availability, rhel7, rsyslog

I would like to print some log messages from the external check script of HAPROXY to rsyslog.
For now, I use “echo” in my external-check.sh script but it does not show up the echo messages. It only shows the haproxy log messages.
Is that possible?

The content of `haproxy.cfg`:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
    external-check
    insecure-fork-wanted

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10m
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          10m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10m
    timeout tunnel          10m
    maxconn                 2048

frontend pa
    bind *:443
    use_backend back-servers

backend back-servers
    option external-check
    option log-health-checks
    external-check command /etc/haproxy/external-check.sh
    server PA-A xxx check inter 30s fall 6 rise 1 ssl verify none
    server PA-B xxx backup check inter 30s fall 6 rise 1 ssl verify none
```

the content of `/etc/rsyslog.d/haproxy.conf`

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514 
$template Haproxy,"%msg%\n"
local0.* -/var/log/haproxy.log
```

example of log output:

```
 Health check for server back-servers/PA-A failed, reason: External check timeout, code: 1, check duration: 30009ms, status: 0/1 DOWN.
 Health check for server back-servers/PA-A failed, reason: External check error, code: 1, check duration: 738ms, status: 0/1 DOWN.
 Health check for backup server back-servers/PA-B failed, reason: External check timeout, code: 1, check duration: 30022ms, status: 0/1 DOWN.
 Health check for backup server back-servers/PA-B failed, reason: External check error, code: 1, check duration: 1590ms, status: 0/1 DOWN
```

As you can see there are no printed messages of my "echo"(s) that I have added to the external check script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer:

Currently, I am using `echo` but I should use `logger` to log messages from the external script to the rsyslog socket via `127.0.0.1`. By default, HAPROXY does not do it for us. It only redirects the log messages of the `haproxy.cfg` events, but not the external script messages.
The trick is to replace all `echo` messages by:

```
logger -p local0.info -t external-script -n 127.0.0.1 "My message"
```